# What is the best way to retrieve the current menu object, regardless of it's type?

Tags: 7

When you call [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7), the first argument defaults to 'node' if no arguments are passed to the function. The code uses the $type variable to check if the current object is of that type, using `$router_item['load_functions'][$position] == $type . '_load'`.

Sometimes, I just want to get the current menu object, regardless of it's type. In other words, when I'm looking at user/123, I want the user object, and when I'm viewing node/456, I want the node object.

Why does menu_get_object force a single entity type?

What is the best way to retrieve the current menu object, regardless of it's type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in that function, it does nothing more than:

```
$router_item = menu_get_item($path);
return $router_item['map'][$position];
```

However, I'm not sure how that will help you, for pretty much all objects, you need to know what it is to work with it as there are just some attributes.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. It seems a good solution, although I'm not 100% sure if it will get me in trouble somewhere down the road. I think it will work for me, because I want to get the value of a certain field, and Field API is supposed to work with all kinds of entities (even though [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7) requires a $type argument as well).

Comment: marcvangend where's solution?

Comment: @marcvangend: Yes, always need $entity and $entity_type when working with entities, because there no general way to extract the type from $entity. (As opposed to $bundle and $id, which you can extract).

Comment: @Berdir: Thanks. At the risk of drifting off-topic... isn't that strange? I'd say that very entity load could just set an $entity->type property automatically. I see that you have already wondered about that at http://drupal.org/node/915058.

Comment: @marcvanged: Yes, there should be something. But.. nodes for example already have a type attribute (which is the bundle, actually), adding that would have broken that. So it would have to be entity_type (which might already be used by other modules, for example userpoints transactions do..).. I think the real solution to this problem is using real classes for entities, not just stdClass, which will maybe happen in D8.

Comment: Thinking about it, you *might* be able to loop over `$router_item['map'] and if you have an object, look at the corresponding %placeholder (try `dpm($router_item)`, it should be somewhere) and then you could maybe guess the entity type based on that (%node, %user, %taxonomy_term, ..). You could then verify that such an entity type actually exists with http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7 as there are load functions which don't return any entity or might not be named consistently...

Comment: You may use $router_item['page_arguments'][0], that also contains the entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $node = menu_get_object();
}
else if (arg(0) == 'user') {
  $user = menu_get_object('user');
}
```

:) or try this:

```
  $obj = menu_get_object(arg(0));
```

although that won't work in a url like this: `http://URL/some_arg0/REQUIRED_OBJECT/some_arg2`

Comment: I considered that too, but the first method is not generic enough for my use case. Regarding the second method, as you say, it doesn't seem right to assume that arg(0) is always equal to the entity type.

Comment: You can use context.